# object_detection using opencv in c/c++ on eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to detect faces and eyes from a video captured by webcam. I am using eclipse and opencv-2.3.1 on ubuntu 11.10. I want to write this code in C/C++. I configured eclipse by looking at the tutorials.I got the code online as [`objectDetection.cpp`](http://fossies.org/dox/OpenCV-2.4.3/objectDetection_8cpp.html)

I am getting the error as below:

```
> **** Build of configuration Release for project opencv_try **** make all 
> Building file: ../objectDetection2.cpp 
> Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler 
> g++ -I/home/vidula/OpenCV-2.3.1/include/opencv -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"objectDetection2.d" -MT"objectDetection2.d" -o"objectDetection2.o" "../objectDetection2.cpp" 
> Finished building: ../objectDetection2.cpp  
> Building target: opencv_try 
> Invoking: GCC C++ Linker 
> g++ -L/usr/lib -L/home/vidula/OpenCV-2.3.1/lib -L/home/vidula/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc -o"opencv_try"  ./objectDetection2.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui 
> /usr/bin/ld: ./objectDetection2.o: undefined reference to symbol 'cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)' 
> /usr/bin/ld: note: 'cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)' is defined in DSO /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3 so try adding it to the linker command line 
> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3: could not read symbols: Invalid operation collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make:
> *** [opencv_try] Error 1
```

I tried linking it to linkers but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is telling you that the `cv::cvtColor` symbol you need is in the `libopencv_imgproc` library, so you need to add that one to your linker options with the option `-lopencv_imgproc`, just like you did with `core` and `highgui`